# Preserve the values inside a loop

Tags: swift

I have this for loop, that iterates thru my records of URLs and make a request. The result of the request is being used again to upload other pending stuffs. But I get an error in this line: `print("id is \(t.url!)")`. I guess the loop is already done when that line of code is being executed that's why it returns nil.
Do you have any recommendation on this?

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Pending")

                        let company_temp = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
                        let company = company_temp as! [Pending]
                        for t in company {
                            let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:t.url!)!)

                            NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {(response, data, error) in
                                print("ticket is \(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))")
                                print("id is \(t.url!)")
                                print("id is \(t.id!)")
                                self.upload_sig(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, id: t.id!)



                        }
```

Comment: what about t.id? is it being executed successfully ?

Comment: you get an unexpectedly nil exception? does the managed object still exist in the repository? does its context still exist?

Comment: No. When I remove the t.url part. The nil error points to t.id

Comment: @Wain it does exist. i tried moving `print("id is \(t.url!)")` outside the NSURLConnection.send.... and it works. I get the value printed.

Comment: You're making an async call, so the entirety of fetchRequest will almost definitely have finished by the time the closure is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say why it doesn't work, but I'd guess that the managed object either doesn't exist any more or that the context it's in has been destroyed, so it can't populate it's data and you get an error.

In your particular situation you don't actually need the object in the code dealing with the completion if the URL request, so don't retain it there. Instead, capture only the id you need rather than the container:

```
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:t.url!)!)
let objectId = i.id!

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {(response, data, error) in
    print("ticket is \(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))")
    print("id is \(objectId)")
    self.upload_sig(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, id: objectId)
```

Note also that you should use ! sparingly and check for `error`s...

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this if you want to access additional temporary values in a closer:

```
func makeFechRequest(url: String, id: String) -> ((NSURLResponse, NSData, NSError) -> ()) {
    let url = url
    let id = id

    func request(response: NSURLResponse, data: NSData?, error: NSError) {
        print("ticket is \(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))")
        print("id is \(url)")
        print("id is \(id)")
        self.upload_sig(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, id: id)
    }
    return request
}
```

then call it like this:

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), 
                                             makeFetchRequest(url: t.url!, id: t.id!))
```

I'm not sure I got all the types correct, but that should get you most of the way

Documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)